# About "if there is a"

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have encountered uses of the phrase "if there is a" but meaning different things.

(1) Here, http://www.math.clemson.edu/~macaule/classes/m16_math4120/slides/math4120_lecture-1-06_handout.pdf, "if there is a" means that the binary operation $\ast$ is part of the group $G$, viz. the group is actually $(G,\ast)$, but

(2) In http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf, "if there is a" means that the Euclidean function $d$ is not part of the Euclidean domain, viz. we merely assume the existence of at least one Euclidean function and do not attach any particular function to the underlying integral domain (is this the right view of Euclidean domains?).

I am confused about use of the phrase "if there is a". I think in (1), "together with a" is a better substitute for "if there is a". What exactly does "if there is a" means?

Comment: Where do you see the respective phrases in each?  I'm not going to read the entirety of the lecture slides.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in (1) the better phrasing would be "A group is a set $G$ together with ..." whereas in (2), "if there is a " is appropriate because we don't assume it is given and we don't (a priori) care which one it is (whereas for a group, the most important thing is to know which one and so the fact that there exists a binary operation is not relevant)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @JMoravitz: For (1) it is p. 5; for (2) it is Defn 1.1 on p. 1.

Answer (score 2):

Example (1) is indeed horrible and awful:

> A set $G$ is a group if the following criteria are satisfied:
>    1. There is a binary operation $∗$ on $G$. ...

In English, "there is" means only "there exists". Hence with this "definition", any non-empty set is a group, and unless $|G|=1$, we have no idea what its neutral element is! While we routinely speak only about "the groups $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C^\times$, $\{\pm1\}$", we should - strictly - mention the respective operation explicitly. It is just that with these well-known cases, the operations are usually understood (namely addition, addition, multiplication, multiplication).
So, yes, a better definition would start

> A tuple $(G,*)$ where $G$ is a set and $*\colon  G\times G\to G$ is a binary operation on $G$ is a group if ...

Another problem with the "definition" in the text is that the enumeration is confusing. Their points "2." and "3." should IMHO be subordinate, not parallel to "1.", as well as "4." should be subordinate to "3." because it references $e$ (which a priori might not be unique). Restructuring accordingly, we arrive at

> A tuple $(G,*)$ where $G$ is a set and $*\colon  G\times G\to G$ is a binary operation on $G$ is a group if
>   $*$ is associative and there exists $e\in G$ (called the identity element) such that $e*g=g*e=g$ for all $g\in G$, and such that for each $g\in G$, there exists an inverse element $g^{-1}$ satisfying $g*g^{-1}=g^{-1}*g=e$.

---

The formulations in your link (2) appear much more "professional" in comparison

Comment: In the final definition, you wrote "the identity element", but we do not know a priori that $e$ is unique. I agree with your opinions about ways to improve the definition of a group, but I saw most textbooks do it in a manner like in (1).

Comment: @yhsai Yes. In a formal context, I'd additinally refarin from calling "the" inverse $g^{-1}$ before showing its uniqueness.